# Empty array size in c

Tags: arrays, c, memory

Probably this is very dumb question. I'm very new to C. Could anyone please explain in simpler way why empty array has 0 byte in memory?

```
int shoot = 2;    // 4 bytes
int zet[4] = {};  // 16 bytes
int raw[] = {};   // 0 bytes
```

**Why variable *raw* takes 0 bytes from memory?**

Comment: Why would you expect it not to?

Comment: `int raw[] = {};` is equivalent to `int raw[0];`.  The number of bytes in an int array of length `n` is `n * sizeof(int)`.  So for an empty array, the number of bytes is `0 * sizeof(int)`, which is zero.  Note that zero-sized arrays are a C extension.

Comment: Here's another way to understand it.  Suppose something is zero feet long.  What is its length in inches?  It's 0 * 12, which is zero inches.  If you prefer metric, suppose something is zero meters long.  What is its length in centimeters?  It's 0 * 100, which is zero centimeters.

Comment: `int raw[] = {};` --> invalid C.

Comment: @chux As I mentioned, it's a C extension.  `gcc` allows it by default.

Comment: @TomKarzes Post not tagged as gcc.  Default, it is not allowed in C.  Sure other languages or extensions can do what they will.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right, which is why I specifically pointed out it's a C extension, i.e. not strictly conforming C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - since the OP does not ask why it does not compile, but does ask why it takes zero bytes, he apparently has a compiler with this extension, though we do not know which one.

Comment: Scott -- can you specify which compiler, since the behaviour is not standard for C?  If there is a relevant tag, please tag it as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `zet`, you give the array a size.
When you declare `raw`, you do not.  When an array is declared with empty square braces, the size allocated for it by the compiler is determined by the number of elements in the initializer.

From a 2007 committee draft of the C standard:

> EXAMPLE 2 The declaration `int x[] = { 1, 3, 5 };` defines and
> initializes x as a one-dimensional array object that has three
> elements, as no size was specified and there are three initializers.

In your case, you have `int raw[] = {};`  There are no initializers, so the array has no elements, and thus is of zero size.

Zero size arrays, however, are not necessarily portable, as they are not part of the C standard.  This is compiler-dependent language extension.

Comment: Further to this, we can infer that the compiler is for a 32bit system from `int shoot` taking 4 bytes. Therefore an array with 4 elements equals 16 bytes in size